# formal completion of smooth morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $f: X\to S$ be a smooth morphism of schemes. Let $p$ be a section.  Let $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_{X, p(S)}$ be the completion $X$ along $p(S)$.  Then I think for every point $s\in S$,  there exists an open neighborhood $ U=\operatorname{Spec} R$ of $s$, such that $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_{X, p(S)} (U)$ is a formal power series over $R$.   How it should be proved? Or where can I find the reference?  Thanks.

Comment: EGA IV$_4$, 16.9.9 and 17.2.1(c') (with $Y=S$ in the latter; i.e., $h = {\rm{id}}_S$ there).  It's ultimately a quite concrete thing, building on the structure of $I/I^2$ that can be read off from the case of the zero-section of affine space over which the given situation is suitably etale.

Comment: nfdc23: Thank you.  To apply 16.9.9,  we need to know the section $p: S\to X$ is quasi-regular,  it doesn't seem we can apply 17.2.1 to get it.  Actually 17.2.1(c') doesn't exist.

Comment: Oops, I made a typo: I should have written 17.12.1 rather than 17.2.1 (and part (c') there exists and addresses exactly the quasi-regular condition).